# Trying to get a large amount of data (column type is "text") from an MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I want to get like 300MB of data (`text` column) out of an MS SQL Server, but with the library I'm using I'm getting an out-of-memory exception as soon as I try to access the field. Unfortunately, I'm bound to that library and cannot switch to something else.

I've tried getting chunks using `SUBSTRING()`, but that returns `varchar` and the max len is 8000, so getting 300MB in chunks of 8K would take forever.

Is there any other way to do this? If I could get that 300MB in 3x 100MB chunks that would be fine, 100MB don't seem to throw an exception. Maybe to somehow split the data server-side?

MS SQL Server Version is 14.0.3436.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: _but with the library I'm using_ Provide more information about your application and the technology it is using. And post the code that throws the error as well as the complete error message - all of it. Note that NO ONE should be using the TEXT datatype - that was deprecated almost 20 years ago. If you can change that, do it now. May not fix the problem but at least it prevents more work at a later time.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or you'll need to do this multiple times?...because there's a multitude of ways to pull the data out of the database (including to a CSV) so that you can then fix it up and load it back into the database in smaller fields.

Comment: @J.D. unfortunately I need to do this multiple times, and to support multiple fields to split the data would be too much of a change for other systems that rely on that, I'll go with changing the column type to `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` and pray that nothing breaks

Comment: I hope you did a backup before you tried to change the type...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've tried getting chunks using SUBSTRING(), but that returns varchar
> and the max len is 8000, so getting 300MB in chunks of 8K would take
> forever.

The reason `SUBSTRING` returns no more than 8000 characters is because you are using the deprecated `text` data type. Use `varchar(MAX)` for large values instead, which allows larger values to be returned with the standard T-SQL `SUBSTRING` function.

The proper way to read data from a legacy `text` column in smaller chunks is with a `READTEXT` statement. Below is an example gleaned from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/readtext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples), with the starting position and length parameterized (integer parameter types).

```
DECLARE @ptrval VARBINARY(16);  
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(pr_info)   
   FROM pub_info pr INNER JOIN publishers p  
      ON pr.pub_id = p.pub_id   
      AND p.pub_name = 'New Moon Books'  
READTEXT pub_info.pr_info @ptrval @StartPosition @Length;
```

Of course, you'll need to first get the length of the value to avoid reading beyond the end of the value. I assume your `SUBSTRING` attempt already does this but that's just a guess without seeing your code.

Comment: Generally this would work, but now there's the problem that it truncates at the first null-byte (seems like `SUBSTRING` is doing so as well). If there's a row with like 10 MB of data and I `SELECT` it completely, it works, but with `SUBSTRING` or `READTEXT`, it truncates. (Would make sense since it's `text`)

Do you know if I can change the row type from `text` to `varchar(max)` or another type that supports that kind of use like `image` without destroying the data?

Comment: @BETSCH, by null byte, do you mean a string terminator (0x00)? Note image is also depreciated. `varbinary(MAX)` is the right type for binary data which you apparently have.

Comment: yes, I'm talking about `0x00`, and yes, it's binary data. 

Alright, I tried to convert `text` to `image` and it doesn't support that anyway. It supports `text` to `varchar(max)` though so that's what I'm doing now, it has to re-create the table though wich I assume will take a long time

Thank you

Comment: @BETSCH So do you have textual data or binary data? If the former it should be in `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` if the latter should be `varbinary(max)`